# How to download a blob from Azure Storage with conditionals?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob

I'm trying to download some images from Azure Blob Storage and I need to put some conditionals into it. I'm working around with file name until now, uploading them with datas on the name so I can use it as conditionals later, but I was wondering some other way to do it.

What I was trying to do so far to get images from a date interval:

```
public async void DownloadBlobAsync(string blobName, string savePath, System.DateTime fromThisDate, System.DateTime toThisDate)
        {          
            var blobs = ListBlobsAsync(); //List all blobs in the current container
            var wantedBlobs = new List<string>(); //After conditionals work, I'll fill up this list with the blob names I want to download

            foreach (var blob in blobs.Result)
            {
                //All stuff about convertion from string do DateTime                
            }

            foreach (var blob in wantedBlobs)
            {
                var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob);
                var downloadedBlob = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

                System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(downloadedBlob.Value.Content).Save(savePath);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution: I'll store the file name into a SQL Database and other usefull datas for me. When I need download some content, I can do a simple query to return the file name and then download through the Azure Storage Package.

Anyway, in case of someone know a better alternative, I'd be glad to know.